# Swift - iOS 11 Translation

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, ios11

I'm currently testing my app on iOS11 and I spot a problem in a controller where I translate a view. The controller is composed of a table view at the top and at the bottom a field to type text.
On iOS9 & 10, the following code allows the bottom field to translate at the top of the keyboard.
However nothing happens on iOS11.

```
func keyboardWillAppear(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        self.bottomView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -keyboardSize.height)
        self.attachmentView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -keyboardSize.height)
        self.classicTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize.height + 10.0, 0.0);
    }
}
```

I should behave like this :
[image]

Do you have an idea why the behaviour has changed ? How can I resolve this problem ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` to `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` like this

```
if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
```

It may help you

Comment: i'm waiting for Xcode beta to finish downloading. Will keep you updated !

Comment: @MelanieJourne Sure